# Dynamic change of Linux root password everyday

Tags: linux, command-line, cron, password

I want to change my root password everyday based on the date. The password will be like a combination of a string and the date. The below code is working fine.

```
echo -e "pass"$(date +"%d%m%Y")"\n""pass"$(date +"%d%m%Y") | passwd root
```

But how to call it each time the system starts and at mid night when the date changes (If the system is on.)?

Comment: Short answer: Don't do it.  It doesn't make sense and you're pretty likely to get locked out and fubar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do that. If you're concerned about security, if someone discovers your password on 1 July, they'll know it on 31 July or 15 September...

To answer your question, if you want to ensure that the password update is done either at a scheduled time or when the system restarts, you want to install `anacron`. It can do periodic scheduling without assuming the system is on all the time. I'm not sure what distribution you're using, but it should be in your package archives.

Alternatively, you can use a mixture of traditional `cron` (changing the password at midnight) and an init script (to handle the case of rebooting) to ensure that the password is always up-to-date.

In either case, put the commands to change the password into a script (say, `/usr/local/sbin/rootpass.sh`) and then call that script using `cron` or `anacron` and from your init script.

Comment: It's not like I'll use the string and date side by side, there may be more difficult combination of these two may be character by character. I'm just asking a way to do it. The string i choose and combination technique will make the password strong enough and unpredictable. I'll try your answer once I get the permission from proxy. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks for the `anacron`. It comes by default with Fedora 20.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bad idea to harden your system by protecting accounts as good as possible as you can. In many situations it will introduce extra hurdles during authentication, but if you're willing to cope with that it's all fine. An important thing to take into account, though, is the risk of *actually introducing more flaws* by increasing the complexity of your system.

It is common practice in systems security and cryptography to only use open-source and thoroughly tested software. Therefore I would not recommend you to use your own script-based solution, but use an existing solution instead.

My suggestion is to use a *Time-Based One-Time Password* (TOTP) as implemented by, for example, `Google Authenticator`. It is a two-step verification method that uses the current time in the generation of the one-time password. In the case of Google Authenticator, this password can be computed by the Google Authenticator smartphone app. It is usually configured in a way that the (fixed) user account password and the one-time password are asked for in sequence. The *Pluggable Authenticator Modules* (PAM) can be used to configure which applications (SSH, display manager, ...) and accounts (root, all, ...) require the one-time password.

Depending on your goals I'd recommend you to read tutorials [[1]](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/) and [[2]](http://www.howtogeek.com/208205/how-to-use-two-factor-authentication-on-your-linux-desktop-with-google-authenticator/) and see if you can adept them to your needs.

Comment: A time-based one-time password can make sense. But a password that's derived from the date with no secret involved, as proposed in the question, is not hardening, it's downright stupid.

Comment: I think the "pass" string is supposed to represent the password, so there actually is a secret involved. That doesn't change anything about the fact that it's probably not a good idea though.

Comment: @Gilles If a string (combination of alphanumeric characters and symbols) makes a password too strong, why adding a date to it will be stupid? I never said I'll use only "pass".

Comment: @RatDon There's no opportunity for any security gain since an attacker who finds `pass` can log in in your scheme, just as with a plain password. There are many places where you lose security: the password has to be stored in cleartext on the server (normally only a hash would be stored, so an attacker who finds e.g. a backup of the server configuration still has to reverse the hash, which is costly for a medium-quality password and impossible for a very strong password); the password has to be manipulated on the client, increasing the risk of a leak.

Comment: @Gilles I've not thought of it for a server machine. I was thinking of my personal machine. I just thought, it'd be more challenging for normal brute-force.

Comment: @RatDon Server vs personal machine is irrelevant. Normal brute force isn't a concern with online attacks if your password isn't laughably weak, and adding the date wouldn't increase resistance much.